# Updating a document in firestore makes the result list go to it's initial form

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function to get the first 10 results from firestore. There is a load more button that executes a function to get the next 10 results and so on. Now suppose I clicked load more once and now we have 20 results. But when I update any one of the documents the entire list goes back to its initial stage and displays 10 results. I guess it's because I have used snapshotchanges to get the results. Is there any way so that the results will stay intact on edit or delete.

```
getAllPosts() {
   return this.db.collection('posts' , ref => ref.orderBy("date", "desc").limit(10)).snapshotChanges();
}
    
getPostsOnClick(startIndex) {
   return this.db.collection('posts' , ref => ref.orderBy("date", "desc").startAfter(startIndex).limit(10)).snapshotChanges();
}

getPosts() {
        this.subscribePoint = this.postS.getAllPosts().subscribe((res) => {
          if (res.length > 0) {
            this.latest_data = res[res.length - 1].payload.doc;
          }
          this.allPosts = [];
          res.forEach((doc) => {
            //pushing inside allPosts array
          });
        });
}
```

I am using the above two functions to get the data. I call getAllPosts() on ngOnInit() and getPostsOnClick() on clicking the loadmore button. I am using angular.

Comment: It would help if you have the code to show how you're loading the page. Are you using RxJS or other state management frameworks?

Comment: I have edited my questions, kindly have a look. @jayg_code

Comment: It looks like after editing a post you are calling again the getPosts() which brings just 10 results. I think that if you previously expanded the list to fetch more post you should keep that in a env variable and pass it as a parameter to replace the limit() and bring the same amount of info again

Comment: @Chris32 No I am not calling getPosts() again, I am updating an array inside a document and it just reset to initial form. Happens for both arrayUnion and arrayRemove

Comment: If you are not calling getPosts() after editing the post, then sharing the code you are using to show the posts or the actios performed after saving the edit could be helpful, instead of just the code to get them from Firestore